# Session state using guice

Tags: java, guice, guice-servlet

I've some session scoped state. First idea to hold it was session scoped servlets. So I bind my servlet like this

```
bind(Foo.class).in(ServletScopes.SESSION);
```

But I get an exception

> > javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlets must be bound as singletons. Key[type=Foo, annotation=[none]] was not bound in singleton scope.

So servlets can't have scope from ServletScopes? Whats the right way to deal with session state (yeah, of course it's better to write state less servlets/classes/applications)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding you *can* bind whatever you want to the session scope, the problem is that in your example `Foo` seems to be an subclass of `Servlet`, and Servlets must be bound in `Singleton` scope.

To resolve this, just bind your *state* (called `Bar`) in session scope and give your `Foo` constructor a `Provider<Bar>` argument (which will be filled in by Guice) so you can access the session-scoped state from the singleton-scoped `Foo` Servlet.

Answer (score 2):

servlets are not created by Guice, but by the servlet container. And they are singletons : only one instance is created by the servlet container to serve all the requests of all the clients.

So binding them to session scope has no sense : Guice can not create one different servlet instance per session.

A servlet should always be stateless (i.e. its state should be global to all the clients, and be accessed in a thread-safe way)

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  But for what purpose ServletScopes was created? And where I should put my session scoped variables?

Comment: Guice actually does create servlets when you're using the guice-servlet extension. It requires that the servlets be singletons because it is consistent with the servlet spec.